# How to extract only the first sentence from the dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to create a game in python called "Save the girl"
One man will kidnap a girl and will keep him in his place and ask money from her family.

To reach his place he will ask three questions. First he will ask one question and if they answer it then he will give a clue to reach his place.

For this I'm storing all the questions and answer in a form of dictionary

Eg:

```
Quiz_dict={"What did the Romans call Scotland?":"Japan","Which company makes the Galaxy 
              series of smartphones?":"Samsung"}
```

Now I just want the first question from the dictionary. How to do that??

I gave the command like

```
keys = "".join(list(Quiz_dict.keys()))
    print(keys[0])
```

But the output was the first letter of the first question (ie.W).
Please help me out

Comment: `keys = list(dict.keys())

print(keys[0])`

Comment: I think the code you are using is somehow wrong! 
try this : ```Quiz_dict.keys()```
Because ```dict``` is a reserved keyword in python!

Comment: Thanks for reminding me Najafi. While typing I forgot that. But now I have edited it.

Comment: In your own words, when you write `"".join(list(Quiz_dict.keys()))`, what do you think the `"".join` part means? What problem do you believe you are addressing by using it?

Comment: @A.Najafi this is incorrect; `dict` is a pre-assigned name, but **not** a keyword. It is perfectly legal to assign to it - you just **should not**, because that makes it harder to access what was already named there (the type itself for dictionaries).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Oh my bad. You are right and thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list(Quiz_dict)[0]
```

should serve the purpose

Comment: Welcome to the community! Have a great time learning and contributing here

Comment: I gave this command and it gave me the first question. Now I made the user to enter the answer for it and I need to check it with the value in the dictionary. How to do that?? I gave command like if(answer == list(Quiz_dict[values])[0])). This gave me an error. Sorry for troubling you . Please help me to solve this

Comment: You query the dictionary with the keys like dict[key]. This can be compared against the user inputs

Answer (score 4):

You have joined the both questions and then FIRST [0] is W.

```
quiz.keys()  = dict_keys(['What did the Romans call Scotland?', 'Which company makes the galaxy series of smartphones> '])
```

Now `list(quiz.keys())` converts it into a list which we can slice

```
list(quiz.keys())[0] --> this gives 'What did the Romans call Scotland?'
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question Arnav!

Answer (score 1):

""" I need to check it with the value in the dictionary. How to do that?? I gave command like if(answer == list(Quiz_dict[values])[0])). This gave me an error. Sorry for troubling you . Please help me to solve this"""

For The Above....

First Of All You can slice the value of a dictionary using dict[values] instead there is
""`dict.values()`"" function which gives a dictionary of Values.
If You do "`list(dict.values())`" then you'll be getting a list of values from which You Can SLICE THE FIRST! USING `[0]`